# How to force text to be on the left and an equation to be centered in a beamer align

Tags: align, center

I have this latex code:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\title{Amsmath example}
\author{Overleaf}
\date{May 2021}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{bettergreen}{RGB}{84,196,94}
\begin{frame}{Formalisation}
    Après une itération de 2-Opt,
\begin{align*}
    &\pi = a_1,\ldots,\textcolor{red}{a_i,a_{i+1}},
    \ldots,\textcolor{red}{a_j,a_{j+1}},\ldots, a_n\\
    \text{
        est transformé en}\\
            &\pi' = a_1, \ldots, \textcolor{bettergreen}{a_i,a_j,} a_{j-1}, \ldots, \textcolor{bettergreen}{a_{i+1}, a_{j+1}}, \ldots,a_n 
    \end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Which compile like this :
[image]

I would like to have "est transformé" aligned with "Après une itération" and the `π` formula centered, with the `π'` one aligned with it.

Comment: If you want write text inside an `align` environment, but as if it was surrounding text, use `\intertext{...}` and not `\text{...}` as in your MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want write text inside an `align` environment, but as if it was surrounding text, use `\intertext{...}` and not `\text{...}` as in your MWE.